# AngularJS 2 Error undefined index1

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm trying to achieve a MeanStack Project, when i'm trying to hit the button update i get this error :
Error: The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1

There is the Update Service

```
 updateLocation(id, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.put('https://exemple.herokuapp.com/api/A/'+id, data)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }
```

the html

```
<form (submit)="onEditSubmit()">
```

And the component.ts

```
  onEditSubmit() {
    this.locationService.updateLocation(this.id,this.location).then((result) => {
      let id = result['_id'];
      this.router.navigate(['locations/', id]);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: you don't need the trailing slash on the router.navigate call -
 should be:    this.router.navigate(['locations', id]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `this.router.navigate(['locations/', id]);` to `this.router.navigate(['/locations', id]);`